# PHP code to generate icons

Tags: php, zend-framework, icons, gd

currently i am working on a huge back-end application in Zend Framework.
A lot of times i end up using wrong icon for some object or action.

**My Question**
Is there any php code to generate icons automatically????

Ofcourse these icons will not be generated magically, best case scenario is that we have a collection of icons which have the type of.

- Object (user,category,product,rss etc)
- Action (add,edit,delete,update etc)

This way we can create icons by mixing different types of icons on the fly.

The code for generating a icon to delete user with 32x32 and delete icon in bottom-right corner of the icon.

```
$icon = new Icon();
$icon->object('user')->action('delete');
$icon->action_align('right')->action_valign('bottom');
$icon->action_height(10)->action_width(10);
$icon->height(32)->width(32);
$icon->create();
```

This is just an example that how can we create a icon which was never exited before.

Comment: I hope to find the library as i mentioned or i have to write it myself.

Comment: I don't think there's an existing one here. But dude, that's a pretty good idea !

Comment: If someone know that type of script please mention.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to export the images, not in the .ico format but a .bmp will be ok.  With [Imagick](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Create-Favicon-With-Imagick.html) it seems you can do directly .ico files.

Comment: Thanks, yes i am pretty confident that GD Library will do.

Comment: me2. You can create an also pngs. I think they are accepted as ico as well.

Comment: Sorry if i misinterpreted, primary objective is to create images png,gif but ico files is a plus.

Answer (score 2):

Hey i can suggest you to create filer like this one :

[Filter that creates image thumbnail](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/83/filter-that-creates-image-thumbnail)

```
<?php
/**
 * Class for thumbnailing images
 *
 * @author Michał Bachowski (michal@bachowski.pl)
 * @package JPL
 * @subpackage   Jpl_Filter
 * @version 0.1
 * @uses Zend_Filter_Interface, IMagick
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Jpl_Filter_File_Image_Thumbnail {
    /**
     * Thumbnail width
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $_width   = null;
    /**
     * Thumbnail height
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $_height  = null;
    /**
     * Information whether to keep ratio or not while making thumbnail
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_bestFit = true;
    /**
     * Information whether crop image or just to resize it
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_crop    = false;
    /**
     * Method sets destination thumbnail width
     *
     * @param  integer  $width
     * @return Jpl_Filter_File_Image_Thumbnail
     */
    public function setWidth( $width = null ) {
        $this->_width = (int) $width;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Method sets destination thumbnail height
     *
     * @param  integer  $height
     * @return Jpl_Filter_File_Image_Thumbnail
     */
    public function setHeight( $height = null ) {
        $this->_height = (int) $height;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Method changes behaviour of filter.
     * Filter will resize image exactly to given dimensions (false)
     * or resize image to fit given dimensions but keep original dimension ratio (true).
     * Setting bestFit to true both dimensions are become mandatory!
     *
     * @param  bool     $bestFit
     * @return Jpl_Filter_File_Image_Thumbnail
     */
    public function setBestFit( $bestFit = false ) {
        $this->_bestFit = (bool) $bestFit;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Method changes behaviour of filter.
     * Filter either just resizes image (false)
     * or resizes with keeping ratio and crop to best fit given width and height (true)
     * If true ommits self::$_bestFit attribute!
     *
     * @param  bool $crop
     * @return Jpl_Filter_File_Image_Thumbnail
     */
    public function setCrop( $crop = false ) {
        $this->_crop = (bool) $crop;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Method filters given file - makes thumb
     *
     * @param  string   $file   path to file
     * @return string   name of file
     */
    public function filter( $file ) {
        $im = new IMagick( $file );
        if ( $this->_crop ) {
            $im->cropThumbnailImage(
                $this->_width,
                $this->_height
            );
        } else {
            $im->thumbnailImage(
                $this->_width,
                $this->_height,
                $this->_bestFit
            );
        }
        $im->writeImage( $file );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i will prefer GD Library so we don't have to be imagemajick dependent.

Comment: that's would be easy , simply make the required changes